# Message type "mediapipe.CalculatorOptions" has no field named "ext"

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, apple-m1, mediapipe

Im trying to write program from course about Advanced Computer Vision based on
mediapipe.
I have Apple M1 processor, so I've installed mediapipe-sillicon for that and opencv-python.

That's my program code:

```
    import cv2
    import mediapipe as mp

    import time

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

mpHands = mp.solutions.hands
hands = mpHands.Hands()

while True:
  success, img = cap.read()
  imgRGB = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
  results = hands.process(imgRGB)

cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(1)
```

And also my camera lights on for 2-3 seconds, and after that I get error message.
And that's error message: Message type "mediapipe.CalculatorOptions" has no field named "ext".

Answer (score 1):

Look at the readme at https://github.com/cansik/mediapipe-silicon

There is an issue with the latest version of protobuf and mediapipe-silicon.

Downgrade `protobuf` to 3.20.1 or lower.

Running

```
pip uninstall protobuf
pip install protobuf==3.20.1
```

worked for me.